# react-bootstrap-typeahead not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am creating a weather app, and i have used **react-bootstrap-typeahead** for autocomplete feature to lookup cities as user types in the typeahead, which are fetched from an api in **handleSearch()** method.

**Problem:  The Typeahead/containing-component is reloading as soon as i type/delete and value is set back to initial default, so its preventing me to type.**

**Full code: [https://github.com/chirag299051/weather-app](https://chirag299051.github.io/weather-app/)**

**App: https://chirag299051.github.io/weather-app/**

Typeahead was working fine until recently; I also moved some state and func. from Search.js to context.js, i dont think that is causing the problem.

**context.js :**

```
export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("day");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);


  useEffect(async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(lURL);
    const result = await resp.json();
    setLocation({
      ...location,
      city: result.city,
      lat: result.latitude,
      lon: result.longitude,
      country: result.country_code,
    });

    console.log("Geo :", result);
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (query) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      fetch(`${cURL}${query}&limit=3&appid=${cKEY}`)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((items) => {
          console.log("items :", items);
          if (Array.isArray(items)) {
            const options = items.map((i) => ({
              city: i.name,
              lat: i.lat,
              lon: i.lon,
              country: i.country,
            }));
            console.log(items, options);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setOptions(options);
          }
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error ;", error);
      setOptions([]);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <context.Provider>...
```

**Search.js**

```html
  const Search = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();
  console.log(myRef);
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
  const { theme, isLoading, location, options, handleSearch } =
    useContext(context);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSearch(location.city);
  }, [location]);

  const filterBy = () => true;
  return (
    <div
      key={Math.random()}
      style={{ padding: "50px 10px", width: "21%", margin: "auto" }}
    >
      <AsyncTypeahead
        ref={myRef}
        filterBy={filterBy}
        id="async-TA"
        isLoading={isLoading}
        labelKey="city"
        minLength={2}
        defaultInputValue={location.city || ""}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        options={options}
        placeholder="City"
        renderMenuItemChildren={(option) =>
          option && (
            <>
              <span>{option.city}</span>
              <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{option.country}</span>
            </>
          )
        }
      />.......
```

Comment: Why do you need a key on the typeahead's container div, and why are you setting it to `Math.random()`? That changes the key on each render, unmounting and and re-mounting the div and its content each time.

Comment: @ericgio thanks for pointing that out, i added it for a different search, bootstrap-typeahead, but i am not using any of those now; i have switched to react-google-places-autocomplete, and is working fine.